# Solution to the difference equation $u_{n+2}=2u_{n+1} + 3u_{n} + 3^{n} (6n + \frac{3}{2})$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find the solution to the following non-homogeneous difference equation:

> $u_{n+2}=2u_{n+1} + 3u_{n} + 3^{n} (6n + \frac{3}{2})$

The homogeneous part was pretty straight forward, but I was having trouble with the particular solution, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look for a particular solution of the form $u_n = 3^n (a n^2 + b n)$.

Comment: Is this true for all general cases of these problems?  Why an^2 + bn?

Comment: In general, for a constant-coefficient linear recurrence where the right side is of the form $\lambda^n p(n)$, where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, if $\lambda$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial (so that $u_n = \lambda^n$ is not a solution of the homogeneous recurrence), then there will be a solution $\lambda^n q(n)$ where $q$ is a polynomial of degree $d$.  If $\lambda$ is a simple root of the characteristic polynomial, $q$ will be a polynomial of degree $d+1$ with no constant term (that's the case in this example).

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a root of multiplicity $m$, $q$ will be a polynomial of degree $d+m$ with no terms in $n^j$ for $j < m$.